# jQuery UI Sortable methods firing too quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm making a seating chart where users can add rows and tables and move tables from row to row. I've added that functionality already. However, the goal is to have a function execute when the user starts dragging and one when dragging has stopped. Right now, the start and stop methods are firing off at the same time and well before the user has started dragging a table. Any advice is appreciated.

```
//Global Vars
var tableCounter = 0;
var rowCounter = 0;
//////////////

$(".rowButton").click(function() {
  rowCounter++;
  $("#rowContainer").append("<div class='tableRow' id='row " + rowCounter + "'><a class='tableButton btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></a><ul class='sortable' ontouchstart='return false;' id='sortable" + rowCounter + "'></ul></div>");

$(".sortable").sortable({
  connectWith: ".sortable",
  start: console.log("start"),
  stop: console.log("stop")
});
$(".sortable").disableSelection();

$(".tableButton").unbind().click(function(){
  tableCounter++;                                                             
  $(this).next().append("<li ontouchstart='return false;' class='ui-state-default' id='"+ tableCounter + "'>Table " + tableCounter + "<br>" + "Test" + "</li>");
});

//Prevent touch selection of text 
$(".ui-state-default, .sortable").on("touchstart", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

});
```

Link to fiddle: http://jsbin.com/xilasun/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
  connectWith: ".sortable",
  start: console.log("start"),
  stop: console.log("stop")
});
```

You are invoking `console.log()` because of the brackets. You need to pass a function name or an anonymous function. Instead, you are passing the *result* of `console.log()`, its *return value*, which is `undefined`.

It should be something like this:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
  connectWith: ".sortable",
  start: myStart,
  stop: myStop
});

function myStart() {}
function myStop() {}
```

Or this:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
  connectWith: ".sortable",
  start: function () {
      console.log("start");
  },
  stop: function () {
      console.log("start");
  }
});
```